# WT901 How to make sense of Euler angle

Tags: sensor, imu

I'm trying to make an angle sensor using the [WT901 Attitude Angle Sensor](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/B11fVGszLsS.pdf)

All I'm looking for is the angle of gravity relative to the Z axis of the device (which I believe is normal to the PCB surface).

I'm reading the Z angle from the device 0x3f, but I'm getting values that don't make sense as I rotate it around that axis.

There's some explanation about Euler angles in the datasheet, so I suspect I have misinterpreted what the angle value represents.

Is that the case? And if so is there a simple way to get what I'm actually looking for? Basically I want the number you'd get out of one of those cube shaped digital angle gauges.

The relevant page in the datasheet:
[image: WT901 angle output datahsheet page]

Comment: So Z angle is "yaw", which is more of a compass heading. The angle "angle of gravity relative to the Z axis of the device" would be roll or pitch for single axis rotations, or a combination of the two for arbitrary rotations. Are you outputting all the angles from the device?